# How do I permanently change the font size in HAN Software's ePub Reader?

Tags: epub, fonts, epub-reader

I know I can easily zoom in or zoom out in [HAN Software's ePub Reader](http://download.cnet.com/ePub-Reader/3000-2125_4-75824080.html) but if I do this, whenever I re-open my ePub, I have to zoom in again.

Is there a way I can set a static font size for ePub Reader?

Comment: Looking at this product, it appears to be primarily for epubs (hence the name I guess). Epub fonts are generally controlled by style sheets inside the epub itself.

Comment: but if the software were decent you should be able to add *your own* CSS which override the default ones. (Pity it usually does not happen).

Comment: I edit to make it clearer this is a particular ePub reader but it would help if you could provide a link to the authors site not some random software site

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest version, as I can see that there is a new release on the 6th of January. You shouldn't have to change the size of the text when you open the eBook back up, as many eReaders save it as a preference. The original size of the text is marked in the CSS.

May I also suggest using different ePub readers, such as [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) as it is used more widely by the eBook community, and no reports of the issue with having to modify your size settings.

If you are thinking of purchasing DRM eBooks in the future, I suggest using [Adobe Digital Editions](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/digital-editions/download.html), as you can still read non DRM eBooks in the software, and it too is more widely known to the community.

Regards,

Phill